# Transfer from Adwords to Google Ads API in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

We are using the BigQuery Data Transfer Service that is based on the AdWords API, but we're missing some of the campaigns. If we write a custom transfer for Google Ads we can get around the issue, but was wondering if there is a timeline yet for a Google Ads transfer seeing as Adwords is being discontinued in April 2022.

Just trying to work out whether to write something custom or hang in there if the new transfer service is imminent. Is there any news on this please?

Comment: What campaigns you are missing? Are you sure your query to check the campaigns is accurate? We run the transfer service for several months and we don't have a missing campaign.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud support wrote me, that so far the existing big query data transfer will continue to work with the old adwords API until a new google ads data transfer service is in general availability, but could not name me a specific timeline ("in the near future").

Comment: I reduced to what can be considered a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can now get the data transfer based on the new google ads api v11:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transfer